# Object to custom class Arraylist

Tags: java, android

I have an array list that is of the type of a class i created. I have written that array list to a file using objectoutputstream. Now i've read it back in as an object but how do i get it back into my arraylist?

```
//Open external storage
        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
       //Get directory path
        File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
        File file = new File(dir, "userAccounts.txt");

        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            UserAccounts tempUser = (UserAccounts) ois.readObject();
            Global.getInstance().userArray.add(tempUser);
            ois.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Global.getInstance().userArray.get(0).aUsername, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Class

```
package com.example.cg4project;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class UserAccounts implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */

    public int aID;
    public String aUsername;
    public String aFirstName;
    public String aLastName;
    public String aemail;
v
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was stored as an ArrayList, you can read it back like this:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
ArrayList<UserAccounts> myArray = (ArrayList<UserAccounts>) ois.readObject();

Global.getInstance().userArray.clear();
Global.getInstance().userArray.addAll(myArray);
```

Comment: if my arraylist is a global arraylist how would i go about storing it in that

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you would put the result in your global array